# Взаимодействие PHP и JS

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток!

**Просьба** не шутить, строго не судить, ну и т.д., я не волшебник, а только учусь.

Короче, тема в следующем:

Нужно из **input** вытянуть символы и в **PHP** сделать запрос к базе по событию "**OnChange**", что-то вроде такого:

```
Select * From $table Where $st Like 'Значение из input';
```

Я понимаю, что действовать нужно с помощью **JS**, но не знаю как. :(

HELP!

Comment: 1. Тут не работаю теги, встроенный редактор работает по другому.

2. У вас два выбора, это использовать формы из HTML без JS или использовать Ajax запросы.

3. И ваш вопрос, скорее, "Как заставить взаимодействовать PHP и JS?", совокупление - это немного из другой оперы.

Comment: @krylach, **markdown** не не слышал. <b>Как тут не шутить то?</b>

Comment: @krylach, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#InputId').change(function(){
   var inputValue=$('#InputId').val();
        $.ajax({
        url      : 'Путь к обработчику',
        type     : 'POST',
        data     : 'inputValue='+inputValue,
        dataType : "json",
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: единственный нормальный ответ,спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

1_Пишем простой php-файл:

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

2_Читаем про [AJAX-запросы](http://javascript.ru/ajax/intro)

Отправляем запросы на созданный php-файл и изучаете возвращаемое значение.

3_Читаете про работу [JS с html](http://learn.javascript.ru/events-change)

Правите AJAX на отправку нужных данных

4_Читаем про работу [PHP и mysql](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/phpintro)

Реализуете нужную вам логику